# Software for monitoring computers and their details on a daily basis

Tags: monitoring, maintenance

I am looking for a software to monitor all the details of computers in my lab.

Details like: computer name , IP address , MAC address, switch_name, port number in switch, disk usage, RAM, etc.

I have about 60 computers and I want the software to alert me on a daily report or so when something was changed (since it can cause trouble).

Comment: What do you mean by "switch_name" and "port number in switch"? Those would seem to be information that would be in some other piece of equipment and not a PC itself as it sounds like a network switch with a cable plugged into a port.

Comment: Managing reports on clients is easy, there are plethora of tools available to you. For example, tools such as CPU-Z and HWInfo outputting to shared files would cover *most* of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a use case for [GRR Rapid Response](https://github.com/google/grr).

- Server needs to be a specific type of Linux installation but clients, *i.e. the monitored machines,* can be Windows, Linux or Mac.
- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Can schedule checks on a periodic basis
- Can trigger alerts

Answer (score 0):

[image]If you can skip the switch details, all the other stuff can be monitored using 10-Strike Network Inventory Explorer (for Windows). It tracks hardware (including CPU, RAM, disks, etc.), software installed, addresses used, disk space. You can configure email notifications for cases when the most critical items are changed.

Comment: Hi @Dmitriy. Thanks but I cannot skip switch details, it is very important since there are many not so smart employees that disconnect lan cables from the ports and forget to connect them back. So we spend a lot of time trying to figure why the lab isn't working..